# По факту поджога женщины — вопросы

Tags: лексика

Как можно поджечь живое существо? Может быть, подожгли то, во что была одета? Может быть, к тому времени тело было бездыханным?

Comment: А где вы такое обнаружили? Контекст есть?

Comment: Из Новостей Соцсети [Россия]: По факту поджога женщины заведено уголовное дело.

Comment: Одно из двух. Или это неграмотно (если подожгли дом), или совсем неграмотно и цинично (если "подожгли" саму женщину).

Comment: Вот похожий ляп: «Женщина загорелась заживо, когда воздушный шар зацепил ЛЭП» от ТРК "Звезда" 22 мая 2016, 12:31.

Answer (score 1):

ПОДЖЕЧЬ, 1. Поднеся, приблизив огонь к чему-л., заставить загореться; воспламенять что-л.  ПОДЖОГ,  1. к Поджечь.

Таким образом, поджечь (свершить поджог), то есть заставить загореться, можно всё (предмет, живое существо, себя и т.д.).

Например: Житель Индии совершил самоподжог в прямом эфире.

Comment: Приблизив огонь к чему-либо? Воспламенять что-либо? Это к женщине относите?

Comment: shampar, а какой глагол, по вашему мнению, применим к живым существам?

Comment: Не открою секрета, наверное: на кострах, например, людей сжигали, а по отношению к кончившим жизнь в огне самостоятельно есть такой термин, как «самосожжение».

Comment: Поджог  и самоподжог - это начало процесса горения, но не его результат, в отличие от самосожжения. Кроме того,  у слова "поджог" есть второе значение - умышленное устройство пожара, это значение имеет ограниченное применение.

Comment: Чтобы возгорелось, нужно воспламенить и, в случае с телом, даже имея открытый огонь, можно лишь обжечь, но никак не зажечь его. Веду к тому, что поджигают, зажигая то, что легко воспламеняется либо горит.

Comment: – shampar, сжигать и поджигать - не то же самое. Почему вы считаете, что тело нельзя воспламенить?Можно!  А ожог может быть результатом воспламенения.

Comment: Живое существо, тем более человека в высоком стиле можно разве "предать огню". Да и то какая-то шероховатость есть. Тут либо сожженее, либо попытка сожжения. И "поджог"  - это ни разу не глагол, а существительное.